# How to make openssl encrypt passwords like php via command line

Tags: openssl

I have this php script (encrypt.php)

```
<?php
    function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key, $encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC")
    {
        $iv = "3571984260";
        $encrypted_string = openssl_encrypt($pure_string, $encryptionMethod, $encryption_key, false, $iv);
        return $encrypted_string;
    }

    echo encrypt ("$argv[1]", 'mysecret');
?>
```

It works, but I am trying to reach the same result via openssl cli (I need it).

But this:

```
echo '12345' | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -iv "3571984260" -k mysecret -a
```

Does not produce the same results as:

```
php encrypt.php 12345
```

Actually the shell version is changing the generated string for each execution, and the php version is generating the same always. I need to obtain the same results as the php script using openssl cli.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added this parameter -nosalt and now the hash is very close, but not identical.

Comment: I see someone saying that mysecret needs to be a hexadecimal key, i generated the hexadecimal key from the word mysecret but i am not having lucky, the generated results are close but not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered it !

The php uses `iv` and `key` variables as strings, and the `openssl` CLI needs the hexadecimal version of the strings, without spaces and new line as I will show.

First I need to convert the iv and the pass strings to hexadecimal using:

Determine the IV hexadecimal equivalent:

```
hexiv=$(echo $(echo -n '3571984260' | od -A n -t x1) | tr -d " ")
```

Determine the `mysecret` hexadecimal equivalent:

```
hexpass=$(echo $(echo -n 'mysecret' | od -A n -t x1) | tr -d " ")
```

Now one more thing the pass for php is not the pass for openssl cli but the KEY:

```
echo -n '12345' | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -iv "$hexiv" -K "$hexpass" -a
```

And now it is working exactly like the php script!

Important: I needed to use `-K` in uppercase or the generated string is not the same.

Comment: You may like to optimise your nested echos into just one: `hexiv=$(echo -n '3571984260' | od -A n -t x1 | tr -d " ")`. Also, should your input string ever be greater than 16 chars you will get newlines from `od`, so you might use `tr -d " \n"`. It is unlikely, but for really long strings of repeated chars, od might elide the output and replace it with a "*", but you can use `od -v` to avoid this.  Finally, if you have `hexdump` it can replace od and tr to give you `hexiv=$(echo -n '3571984260' | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"')`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and upvote!  The echo inside echo remove \n by itself, but good tips! This echo inside echo is good for removing double spaces too for some unknown reason, but not in that case, because i need to remove every spaces, so i am using tr.

Comment: -k is for passphrase, -K for key