# cant echo >> sudoers file 'permission denied: /etc/sudoers'

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, echo

I wanted to write a script to add some tools to my VPS or VMS and I write something like that

```
# Edit sudoers
echo -e "${GREEN}Configure sudoers...${NOCOLOR}"
echo
echo '# Allow user to use sudo without passwd' >> /etc/sudoers
echo '$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

this script run as Sudo and i test echo $USER in Sudo is the user name, not root I mean I'm kind of new so I did not know that and write this but when I test it I'm getting error `permission error` i don't know what to do I did some search but can't find anything

Comment: The answer to the title of the question [is here on redirecting stdout to a file to which one does not have write permission](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on). Therefore, I think the title might be edited a bit.

Comment: How exactly are you running this script? You said you run it as sudo, but are you running the script itself as root, or just the commands in it? Also, how are you running it in relation to the VPS/VMS/whatever?

Comment: Even if you run this with `sudo`, the redirection is done by the parent process, which is unprivileged. Also,  single quoting (`echo '$USER...` prevents interpretation of `$USER`. To demonstrate: `echo $USER; echo '$USER'; echo "$USER"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the safest way for programmatically writing to a file with root privileges?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276624/what-is-the-safest-way-for-programmatically-writing-to-a-file-with-root-privileg)

Comment: @waltinator, if those commands are in a script, and the script is run with `sudo scripts`, the redirections inside will be done by the privileged shell which sudo ends up launching.

Comment: @notnexn and the confusion with `sudo echo ... > ...` is why you need to show what exactly it is you're trying to do. The full command line, and the associated error message.  Just copy-paste them from the terminal, and [edit] your post to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
sudo echo "# This is a comment" >> someFile.txt
```

You can use:

```
echo "# This is a comment" | sudo tee -a someFile.txt
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget the `-a` flag for the `tee` command, otherwise you will end up *overwriting the whole file* with the new comment line.

Read more about `tee` here:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html

Comment: they don't seem to be using `sudo echo`. At least that's not what they're showing in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have three things to point out there. One, you should really use `visudo` to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file, even if you set `$EDITOR` to a script that echoes that content. The other is that it is sub-optimal to let any user run any command without a password. Finally, `$USER` will equal root, so that will be pointless.

If you really want to do that, make a separate script that has this in it:

```
echo '# Allow user to use sudo without a password' >> $1
echo "$PERSON ALL=\(ALL\) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> $1
```

Second, make yet another script that runs your main script like this:

```
sudo "env PERSON=$USER /your/script/here"
```

That should tidy it up a bit, because you can be sure that the whole script is being run as root, and `visudo` keeps backups in case you screw up the sudoers file.

Comment: Or, rather than editing the sudoers file directly, create a separate file per user that just contains that line: `echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/$USER`.

Comment: That's also a good idea. The point of visudo is just not irreversibly screwing up the main file.